# How to use a flask variable inside src script tag?

Tags: javascript, flask

The below hardcoded string will work:

```
<script src="https://gist.github.com/xxxxxxx.js"></script>
```

I have the same string in a db and using the below will not work:

```
    <script src={{ project.link }}></script>
```

where {{ project.link }} = https://gist.github.com/xxxxxxx.js

tried:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" id="myScript">
      var link ='{{ project.title }}'
    </script>
```

with this below:

```
  <script>
      document.getElementById('myScript').src = link;
  </script>
```

Does not work too.

Comment: Your first example should work if you add quotes.  `<script src="{{ project.link }}">`.  Remember that Flask doesn't care about quotes.  It's just looking for the braces.

Comment: I'm still not able to view the gist page. I've tried putting the quotes in the db and as you showed above.

Comment: Show us what the final HTML looks like, in View Source.

Comment: There was an error in the db string causing the issue